# ImportError: module 'setuptools.dist' has no 'check_specifier' attribute

Tags: installation, ceph

Ceph teuthology installation fails with following error on Ubuntu 14.04, kernel 4.4.0-51-generic:

> ```
> ImportError: <module 'setuptools.dist' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.pyc'> has no 'check_specifier' attribute
> ```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It was due to older setuptools version. I updated setuptools as follows:

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

It installed setuptools-31.0.0 and that worked.

Comment: Thanks. It was also due to an old pip 1.5 on my side. Don't forget to `pip install -U pip` !

Answer (score 5):

For python 3 and later 3.x, use pip3

```
sudo pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```

No need to use sudo for a virtual environment or in admin console of windows,so use simply

```
pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```