# Pycharm - Python packaging tools not found

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, python-3.5

I'm trying to install packages in Pycharm for python3.5 interpreter.
It says,

> Python packaging tools not found. **Install packaging tools**.

But when I try to install,
[It gives this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gahv9.png)

```
AttributeError: module 'setuptools.dist' has no attribute 'check_specifier'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2, Pycharm Community edition 2017.1.1

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Run this command and you should be able to install the packaging tools in Pycharm:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

It's python3-pip, not python-pip if you are using the Python3 interpreter.

Comment: Just installing python3-pip and executing pycharm by sudo did the trick. Thanks

Comment: I get the same error - and python3-pip is installed - what else might be missing ?

Comment: Any suggestions for windows?

Comment: Thank you! +1. After that, I have encountered to another problem: AttributeError: module 'setuptools.dist' has no attribute 'check_specifier' and next solution found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141657/importerror-module-setuptools-dist-has-no-check-specifier-attribute
I had to upgrade also my setuptools. Maybe for someone it will be helpful.

Comment: Removing all 'corrupted'(marked red) interpreters from the list in Pycharm helped me

Comment: After running this and clicking 'Install packaging tools' again, PyCharm 2022.1.3 was smart enough to prompt for sudo password and then proceed with installing the rest. No need to launch PyCharm with sudo as @GouthamGanesan described. I'm guessing this was a PyCharm improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when upgrading my Ubuntu to a newer version and it auto-installed an updated version of python and set it as the primary python version (3.8 --> 3.10).

I deleted the venv folder for the project and created a new one using the current python version (3.10) which seemed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When i open pycharm with python 3.8 interpreter '+' option is not clickable (additional packages)after typing sudo apt install python3-pip it works and '+' option is clickable .....so try it if you re facing same problem.