# Difficulty importing packages to interpreter in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I am trying to run a django project in pycharm on Ubuntu 20. I have a virtual environment set up in pycharm as so
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46p79.png)

I have clicked on the link saying install package tools. Pycharm just seems to load something but it doesn't let me add any package still.
When I click on edit configuration, it tells me `Error: Django is not importable in this environment`.
Going back to the python interpreter page as shown in the image, I see that I cannot even click on the add button to add packages. I have a requirements folder with `base.txt`, `local.txt` and `production.txt` inside of it. I only have ONE interpreter available as well. I am not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: Just follow the link pycharm is suggesting. You should have pip and setuptools in an empty project.

Comment: @Goion I have tried that, I still cannot add any packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm - Python packaging tools not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567996/pycharm-python-packaging-tools-not-found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm error Django is not importable in this environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363661/pycharm-error-django-is-not-importable-in-this-environment)

Comment: @Goion I have looked at that.. I have pip installed. Still same message.

Comment: @rzlvmp In order to install Django, I need to be able to click the plus icon in the Python interpreter, so I need to figure that out first.

Comment: Delete that venv and create a new one. Either create the new venv from inside the IDE or create a new venv using the command line. But after it's created it must have setuptools already installed when you open the interpreter. In any case, carefully follow those linked threads and one of them will work for you.